# NFS - Multiple Mounts, Heavy Write, Performance Degredation

Tags: linux, nfs

I have 6 NFS Mounts (1GbE) on a RHEL 5.7 system with 10GbE.

Iperf shows full link saturation to all 6 interfaces simultaneously.

There is a bottleneck somewhere within the nfs client system, but I cannot find it.

It can write to 3 of the mount points simultaneously with full link saturation, but when this number is increased to 6, each point only writes at about half of link speed.

I am suspicious about the number of nfsiod threads, but cannot find this option/setting anywhere.

The problem also appears to exist on Ubuntu, but manifests differently - it completes several transfers at full speed, and some with degraded performance. On RHEL, the performance of all transfers is degraded.

How can I troubleshoot further? Thanks.

Comment: is rhel 5 clien or server? do you use nfs 3 or 4? wh9ch wsize an r size are used. which fs?

Comment: nfs3, rhel5 client. thanks for your help. tried various wsize/rsize with no impact.

Comment: looking at top, only 3 rpciod processes at a time are having much utilization, maybe a clue.

Comment: What are the characteristics of underlying storage? Number of disks, RPM, SATA/SAS, storage controller? How high is CPU utilization on the server?